# React Redux with React native Unexpected context found on stack. This error is likely caused by a bug in React. Please file an issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-context

I am trying to understand redux and react-redux. I have created a minimal snack that is supposed to pass down some data to a grandchild. But on running the app I keep getting the error

> Device: (96:380) Unexpected context found on stack. This error is
>   likely caused by a bug in React. Please file an issue.

Are these libraries not supposed to be used together? I am pretty new to all of these.

Here's the reproducible demo:
https://snack.expo.io/@adititipnis/context-poc

Comment: This sounds like maybe you have used incompatible versions of react or react-native and react-redux